# Definition of ring-homomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

If we choose a ring $R$ with unit $1$ then for $r\in R$ the map $R\rightarrow R,s\mapsto rs$ is not a ring-homomorphism since $1$ is not mapped to $1$?

It seems false that this map is not a ring-homomoprhism...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that reason *and* (most of the times) for the fact that $\phi(ab)=rab$, which is in general not equal to $\phi(a)\phi(b)=ra\cdot rb$. If $R$ is commutative, it is a homomorphism of $R$ as $R$-module. If $R$ is not commutative, it still is a homomorphism of $R$ as *right* $R$-module (but in general not as a *left* $R$-module).

Ring-homomorphisms are the functions $\phi:R\to S$ which satisfy:

1. $\phi(1)=1$
2. $\phi(a-b)=\phi(a)-\phi(b)$
3. $\phi(ab)=\phi(a)\phi(b)$

Condition (2) is often substituted with the equivalent condition "$\phi(a+b)=\phi(a)+\phi(b)\text{ and }\phi(-a)=-\phi(a)$"